# What is the most efficent way to populate a table using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using a jQuery script for a table which paginates and searches through data. It works and functions as it is supposed to.

I'm populating the table with data which consists of over 1,000 records and I'm currently using a PHP while statement to populate it.

Within the `table` code I have this statement, first I execute the query to get the data, `$article = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY published DESC");`

Then I use the while statement to populate - 
`while($articles = mysql_fetch_array($article)) {`

Whilst this does work, the page load time is so poor and takes a long time to load. Obviously this isn't the most effective way of populating. Is there an 'easier' and efficent way of doing this?

Comment: Since you are paginating, can't you only return a page of data at a time? [PHP Link](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_paging.php)

Comment: The query time may be your bottleneck.  Add an index on the `published` column to speed the ordering.

Comment: use `limit` and only get back the visible rows - or is that how your pagination works already ... indexing on your `where` and `order` columns is also a must

Comment: Use pagination on the query in php.  not jquery.  and to speed up loading new pages, use ajax.

Comment: If you are using the DataTables plugin with jQuery, it loads the **ENTIRE** table and then hides part of it for pagination. That could be where your problem is.

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is deprecated and should not be used. Have a look at `MySQLi` and/or `PDO_MySQL` instead.

Comment: @cillosis datatables can also just load the visible records [excellent example here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) (PHP code included)

Comment: @ManseUK I wasn't aware of the server side options. Thanks for pointing that out! My statement still partially stands if OP is using DataTables **and** is not using the server side option.

Comment: @cillosis I'm actually using TinyTable Sorter, so the pagination is done through JavaScript rather than the actual PHP.

Comment: @CraigJones and thats your problem .... the whole table is loaded into the page then the pagination is performed ....

Comment: @ManseUK What would you recommend is the best way of paginating before rather than after?

Comment: @CraigJones either write your own as suggested below or use a plugin like http://datatables.net that already does what you want. [This is a complete PHP example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your data types to be smaller so you are downloading less though.

You probably have a lot of excess data you are downloading by selecting * instead of the specific tables you need as well.

You can also use LIMIT x to limit the number of articles/results you get (you probably don't actually need 1000 on a page right?..)

Other than that, there isn't much you can do to speed it up because it is taking so long to load due to the time it takes to download from the database, not the efficiency of the PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

Are you showing all 1000 articles on one page or are you using jQuery to page through sets of, say, 50 at a time?

If you are doing the latter, why are you getting all 1000 records? Instead you could change your sql to something like this:

```
 $startRecord = N // set to some value, initially 0
 $numRecords = 50;

 $query = "SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY published DESC limit $startRecord, $numRecords";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
```

This would get the first 50 records. Modify the $startRecord var to get other records from your data set.

Comment: +1 yep... in short, using `$startRecord` w/ page number is good idea to speed up entire process, like `$startRecord = ($pagenum-1) * $numRecords;` (this example).

Comment: How would I go about implementing this? if I'm paginating using jQuery, which is still fetching the records and then sorting the data. If I adjust my current sql to the above, wouldn't that just limit the first 50 records (for example), how would I then sift to the next 50 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

(mysql)OFFSET + (php)PAGINATION  + (mysql)OPTIMIZATION (such as Index key...)